# Case syntax question

Tags: formula, process-builder

Having issues with the following Case function. I'm getting an error in Process Builder: **"The formula expression is invalid: Syntax error. Missing ')'** . I can't seem to figure out what I'm missing. I'm trying to update the associate campaigned based on the name of the opportunity. Here is the case formula:

```
CASE([Opportunity].Name,"Individual Ticket",7011I000000CZq1QAG,
"Chosen Partner",7011I000000CZq6QAG,
"Bronze Partner",7011I000000CZprQAG,
"Silver Partner",7011I000000CZqBQAW,
"Exclusive Gold Partner",7011I000000CZqGQAW,
"Couple's Tickets (Admit 2)",7011I000000CZqLQAW,7011I000000CZqLQAW)
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: a super helpful tool for formula building if you are using Chrome is https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforcecom-enhanced-fo/cnlnnpnjccjcmecojdhgpknalcahkhio/ - syntax highlighting, paren balancing, and more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ID values need to be in quotes, too:

```
CASE([Opportunity].Name,
"Individual Ticket","7011I000000CZq1QAG",
"Chosen Partner","7011I000000CZq6QAG",
"Bronze Partner","7011I000000CZprQAG",
"Silver Partner","7011I000000CZqBQAW",
"Exclusive Gold Partner","7011I000000CZqGQAW",
"Couple's Tickets (Admit 2)","7011I000000CZqLQAW",
"7011I000000CZqLQAW")
```

Everything else looks okay to me.

Comment: Thanks! That was it!